# Racket - make-closure and apply-closure

Tags: racket, interpreter, value-of

So I'm fairly inexperienced with Racket but am writing an interpreter.

I've been unable to find insight as to what exactly a closure is, or how "apply-closure" or "make-closure" would be defined/explained.

I'm writing just a value-of interpreter with match, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Given example from class -

```
(define value-of
 (lambda (exp env)
  (match exp
  [`,b #:when (boolean? b) b]
  [`,n #:when (number? n)  n]
  [`(zero? ,n) (zero? (value-of n env))]
  [`(sub1 ,n) (sub1 (value-of n env))]
  [`(* ,n1 ,n2) (* (value-of n1 env) (value-of n2 env))]
  [`(if ,test ,conseq ,alt) (if (value-of test env)
                              (value-of conseq env)
                              (value-of alt env))]
  [`(begin2 ,e1 ,e2) (begin (value-of e1 env) (value-of e2 env))]
  [`(random ,n) (random (value-of n env))]
  [`,y #:when (symbol? y) (apply-env env y)]
  [`(lambda (,x) ,body) (make-closure x body env)]
  [`(,rator ,rand) (apply-closure (value-of rator env)
                                  (value-of rand env))])))
```

Comment: Please read Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, chapter 4 deals with interpreters and it'll explain all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```
(define x 42)
(define f (lambda (y) (+ y x))
(f 1)
```

The question is: what information needs to be available when `(f 1)` is evaluated?
Somehow the value if `x` needs to be stored for later use.
One solution is to store a copy of the entire environment in the closure.

```
(struct closure (args env expression))
(define f (make-closure '(y) the-environment '(+ y x))
```

A better solution is to analyze the expression and only store free variables in the closure. See SICP or EoPL for details.